# People Picker Lookup Column

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-online, people-picker

I have two different list. In the first list are some people picker columns. 
Is it possible to create a lookup column for list 2 to add the user from the first list?
I know it isn't supported in Sharepoint, but i hope someone have an idea to solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directly the "People Picker" column will not be supported as a lookup in another list. For this scenario, you can create another column of "single line of text" type.
Then by using a simple workflow you can update the newly created column with the value from "People Picker column" (Workflow should be triggered on new item added/modified).

Now you can refer the newly created column as a lookup column in any other list.

Comment: That's a very good solution. The only problem is that the workflow creates a new version of my item. Is it possible to stop creating a new version if you use a workflow? I have 5 or 6 "people picker" in my list and the Workflow starts when one this columns are be changed. so it could be possible that my "wokrlfow copy" of the peoaple picker creates 5 o6 versions of my item.