# Is it possible to lookup people picker type field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, lookup-column, schema

Is it possible to lookup a people picker type field from a list. I have tried OOTB as well. But I couldn't do it through OOTB even.
I need something like as following: Here "Person" is a people picker type field.

```
<Field Name="Person" ID="{d74b3913-2c09-4e17-ad28-3ec11ac4be31}" DisplayName="Person" Type="Lookup" List="Lists/Persons" ShowField="Person" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use **people picker** column type as a **lookup** field.

Refer this link for reference,

- http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.in/2012/01/sharepoint-not-all-column-types-can-be.html
- [People Picker Lookup Column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78548/people-picker-lookup-column)

As we are working in SharePoint, we have to play within its boundaries...;)

Hope this will help you.