# Lookup Column with People Picker

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, people-picker

I have a small requirement where in i have a People Picker Field in List A.
Now i have a Look-up column in List B. 
**How do i get the People Picker Unique Values in Look-up Column.**

Example

**Employee Name(People Picker) in List A**
Jayant 
Vishal 
 Ashwini 
Jayant 
Vishal

**Employee Name(Lookup Column) in List B**
Jayant 
Vishal 
Ashwini

How can i achieve this without workflow?

Answer (score 0):

The "Person or Group" column is not supported as a lookup in another list.

The only way to achieve this is by workflow.

Reference: [People Picker Lookup column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78548/people-picker-lookup-column?rq=1)

Comment: There must be a way to auto populate through CSOMS. Do you have answer to that?

Comment: One more question, is it possible to get people picker data and appending it in choice field?

Comment: The people picker textbox itself is of searchable choice type. So you can just use SharePoint people picker box.  [Refer](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/client-side-people-picker-in-sharepoint-2013)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, we can use jQuery with REST API to achieve it. Use a single line of text field to instead of lookup field, and using REST API and jQuery to get all the Employee Names from **List A**, and hide this text field add a drop down control in the list form. The following example for your reference.

1.Create a custom list "**List A**", and create a user field "**Employee Name**".

2.Create a custom list "**List B**", and create a single line of text field "**Employee Name**".

3.Add the following code into a script editor web part into New/Edit form page in **List B**.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var listId="6C9991B2-50A4-4755-9E4B-9D391C2774FE";
    var employeeName=$("input[title^='Employee Name']").val();
    $("input[title^='Employee Name']").hide();
    $("input[title^='Employee Name']").after("<select id='EmployeeField' class='ms-RadioText'><option value=''></option></select>");
    var allEmployeeNames=getAllEmployeeNames(listId);
    $.each(allEmployeeNames,function(i,employee){
        if(employeeName==employee.Employee_x0020_Name.Title){
            $("#EmployeeField").append("<option selected='selected' value='"+employee.Employee_x0020_Name.Title+"'>"+employee.Employee_x0020_Name.Title+"</option>");
        }else{
            $("#EmployeeField").append("<option value='"+employee.Employee_x0020_Name.Title+"'>"+employee.Employee_x0020_Name.Title+"</option>");
        }       
    });
    $("#EmployeeField").change(function(){
        $("input[title^='Employee Name']").val($(this).val());
    });
})
function getAllEmployeeNames(listId){
    var results;
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'"+listId+"')/items?$select=Employee_x0020_Name/Title&$expand=Employee_x0020_Name/Id",
        type: "GET",
        async:false,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.d.results.length>0){
                results=data.d.results;
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //alert("Error");
        }
    });
    return results;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi LZ_MSFT, 
I tried your method, the employee name field in list b chages to Dropdown but there are no values being populated in the dropdown, Please help me with this.

Comment: Check if the list name is "List A" and check the "Employee Name" field internal name of the list A.

Comment: i did both of them. One query, getbytitle function involves list name or internal list name?

Comment: Hi LZ_MSFT , i am not able to go into the success function as it directly goes into the error part and throws an error and also the result variable returns undefined.

Comment: Access the URL "http://yoursite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List A')/items" in browser to check if it works. My test environment is SharePoint 2013/Online, did you use SharePoint 2010?

Comment: No, i am using SharePoint 2013. and the site url that i am using gives an error saying it is not found. is it possible to get the list by list id?
i have the list id, so maybe that can work

Comment: Yes, we can get list items base on list guid using rest api. Like this "/_api/web/lists(guid'6C9991B2-50A4-4755-9E4B-9D391C2774FE')/items"

Comment: Hi LZ_MSFT,  Could you please tell me what all do i have to change in the above code so i do not make a mistake while uploading the code. Also i am getting an error on line 9 in console saying 'Cannot read property 'Title' of undefined'. Please help

Comment: If it still not works, I suggest you provide some screenshots about your List A and field name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84175/discussion-between-jayant-khushalani-and-lz-msft).